# Display a specific value of Json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I would like to add a specific value of JSON in a variable and then print it.My code is:

```
$jd_user = json_decode($result);
print_r($jd_user);
```

And the result of this is:
[image]

I want to print the highlight of the above picture  CU26943

I try :

```
$client=$jd_user->data->user;
echo $client;
```

But I receive error:

> Trying to get property of non-object in  (..)

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to see without propper formatting, but looks like `$jd_user->data[0]->user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is an array not an object. You should use:

```
$jd_user = json_decode($result);
$client=$jd_user->data[0]->user;
echo $client;
```